# visual studio offers to convert Expression-body in c# to block body for method : IDE0022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, c#-6.0

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        => Json(_itemMasterBL.GetItemMaster()?.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I have the above piece of code as expression-bodied method (c# 6.0).

But in visual studio 2017 quick actions (ctrl + .) it makes this suggestion:

**IDE0022: use block body for methods** as follows:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        return Json(_itemMasterBL.GetItemMaster()?.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

What is the meaning of this suggestion? Is it proposing that this change should be preferred for some reason? Or is it just offering the possibility as a convenience?

Comment: "Suggesting" or "offering"? There's a big difference.

Comment: Ok.. Offering :)  @JonSkeet

Comment: You can choose your preferred style (and the way VS will inform you about violating style rules) for some cases under `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Code Style`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Converting between expression body and block body is somewhat tedious and something you might want to do fairly often. Which is why I think VS offers it as a refactoring, it isn't a statement of one being better than the other.